# EF Core with Postgres can't translate Array.Contains() query

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have an entity with field defined as array of GUIDs. And I want to know if there some rows in DB which field contains value passed as argument.
According to [docs](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html#operation-translation) I'm able to make a `.Where(x => x.ArrayField.Contains(arg))` or `.Where(x => x.ArrayField.Any(f => f == arg))` (also can wrap arg into a single-element array and do `.Any(f => array.Contains(f))`) call.
But in fact I'm getting this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Error generated for warning 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryClientEvaluationWarning: The LINQ expression 'where {[x].Ids => Contains(Id_2)}' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.'. This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID 'RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning' to the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or 'AddDbContext'.
```

My query looks like this:

```
var entities = await context.Query<Entity>
    .Where(x => x.Ids.Contains(Id))
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

Why it is wrong? Or there should be some extra-configuration?
On DB side column defined as `uuid[]`. I'm not a Postgre pro, but assume it's enough for database.

**UPD**: the field is defined on C# side as `IReadOnlyCollection<Guid>`. Can this be a reason for the translator to fail?

**UPD2**: changing `Ids` types to `Guid[]` or `IEnumerable<Guid>` didn't help. The same error.

Comment: `ReadOnlyCollection` defines its own `Contains()` method, but only on the concrete `ReadOnlyCollection` type, not on the `IReadOnlyCollection` interface. Which one does your code use?

Comment: I have a public `IReadOnlyCollection<Guid>` prop which is just a shortcut to an inner array: `private Guid[] ids; public IReadOnlyCollection<Guid> Ids => ids;`

Comment: What if you try `x.Ids.AsEnumerable().Contains(Id)`?

Comment: Change your `IReadOnlyCollection<Guid>` to `IEnumerable<Guid>`.  I *think* IReadOnlyCollection makes a copy of the collection.

Comment: @haim770: expectantly it fails with `Could not parse expression 'x.Ids.AsEnumerable()'`

Comment: @Neil: I think it could fix things for me, but such changes are unwanted because it will break project's API convention. and who knows how it can affect the application ;) so I'm trying to find a solution for existing object signature, if any I will always have an option with changing the type.

Comment: Seems like Array columns is not supported by EF, use a pivot table instead if you could. Otherwise go to the raw SQL command and yes it is not trivial... In general it`s better to enforce relational database features - such as Pivot table... Otherwise if not using SQL features - why not go to the No SQL world ))

Comment: @dotFive If you change the interface to use `IEnumerable<>` and it does actually work, then I think you have your answer.

Comment: Do you solve this error?

Comment: @Glebka Hi. Seems yes but honestly I don't actually remember what was the initial problem. Sorry if this answer is not what you expected.